# Remove "Delete" option from Windows 7 Context Menu?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Well it ever so often happens that I want to click rename and I end up clicking delete.For delete I use the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key so I have no need for the context menu option.

I have tried several programs but unfortunately they only remove context menu items added by third party programs or some Windows´s own thing that I don't want to remove.

I found one program that potentially could do what I want it to(not 100% sure tho): [here](http://www.hace.us-inc.com/mmm.shtml) but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I made a small mockup how it looks now and how I want it to look:

[image]

Alternatively if this can't be removed then maybe there's a way to make it do nothing (without breaking the delete functionality globally) or make it greyed out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For delete i use the DEL key so i have no need for the context menu option.

In that case, just get used to using **F2** for Rename.

I looked into editing the registry to shorten context menus in Windows, but I only found ways to remove entries made by third-party programs (and possibly added Microsoft programs).

Comment: Ok.I guess i have to live with it then.Thanks for the answers.

Comment: It's a useful suggestion, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Wouter But it was good enough for the person who asked the question and it appears that there is no full answer.

Comment: @paradroid: never mind, seems i was misinformed on what "accepted answer" means. It does indeed make more sense to repost the question if I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the menu in question is at least in part in the **shell32.dll.mui** file, located @

windows\system32\en-us (depending on your OS region/language)

Using *resource hacker*, you need to <strike>modify menu 210</strike> several menus! (Ctrl+**F**ind "&Delete", F3 to *Find Next* :)

```
MENUITEM "Cu&t", 24, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "&Copy", 25, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "&Paste", 26, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "", 65535, MFT_SEPARATOR, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "Create &shortcut", 16, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "Rena&me", 18, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED
MENUITEM "", 65535, MFT_SEPARATOR, MFS_ENABLED
```

the question is, **IF** I remove the delete context menu <strike>entry #17</strike> entries, is the delete function (via that why-are-you-so-close-to-my-home-key-DELETE button) similarly disabled? Let's see.

**NB: 64-bit users** also need to modify the file @ windows\syswow64...

You may need to take ownership of the files first (I recommend googling 'add **take ownership** to context menu') copy the file (shell32.dll.mui), then modify and save changes to the copy (after compiling in resource hacker), THEN replace the sys file (backup by renaming original to shell32.dl.mui.whateveryouwant)with the copy. **FINALLY**, run mcbuilder (in sys32)... Gonna try it now, on a new build I've mounted to E: [here's an illustration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsGA1nvIEFrcW9wbG5SWlJHWGM/edit?usp=sharing):

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no way to remove/disable the predefined options (ie, Delete).

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to remove the delete command from the recycling bin context menu @ http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/142/1/How-to-hide-the-Delete-command-from-Recycle-Bin-context-menu-in-Windows-Vista.html, so there may be hope...still looking.